# Div Tags and a header

Tags: html, css, containers

Hi everyone im currently trying to make a website I have drawn out the design, and have started trying to make the header using several div tags,a logo image ,bottom border , and buttons.
Heres my basic outline of what im trying todo:(Sorry its blurry but usable)
[image: concept]

This is the current Result it looks bad.
[image: result]

Finnaly here is the code responsible can anyone see where i messed up? the line should cover most of the page from the logo to right side so it has to be the div container

```
<html>
<head>

    <style>
    body{ background-image: url("wood texture.jpg");
    }
    .header{
            position:relative;
            width:100%;
            height:10%;
            <!--border-style:solid;
        border-color:black;
        border-width:0px 0px 10px 0px;-->

        }

        .headlogo{
        width:25%;
        height:100%;
        position: absolute;
        padding 0;
        margin:0;
        }
        .headline{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0px 0px 0px 60%;
        <!--padding:0px 0px 0px 25%;
        position: relative;
        left:25%;
        top:0px;-->
        float: right;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:black;
        border-width:0px 0px 10px 0px;
        }



    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="" class="header">


    <div id="" class="headlogo">
     <img src="logo.png" alt="" style="width:25%; height:50%; margin-right:10px; float:right;"
    </div>

    <div id="" class="headline">
    Buttons will go in here and look supper cool but first this needs to stretch all the way to the right from about where the logo stops
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing ` />` on the IMG tag

Comment: You should comment css with /* comment */ and not with <!-- comment -->. Last one is for html tags only.

Answer (score 4):

You were just using the wrong line comments for your css.

HTML is `<!-- something here -->`

CSS is `/* something here */`

And like noted in the comments, you did not close out your image using `/>`

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/50/

**since you asked in the comments, I will add it here** Css line comments in a `.html` file will not appear to be commented out while using notepad++, to test it try using the css line comments in a `.css` file using notepad++, you will see in fact that it does work. I created this fiddle to show you that the `/* */` is in fact the correct line comments when inside `<style>` tags. https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/52/

And after all this if there is still a question you can watch this little clip: http://docs.emmet.io/actions/toggle-comment/

```
body{ background-image: url("wood texture.jpg");
    }
    .header{
            position:relative;
            width:100%;
            height:10%;
            /*border-style:solid;
        border-color:black;
        border-width:0px 0px 10px 0px;*/

        }

        .headlogo{
        width:25%;
        height:100%;
        position: absolute;
        padding 0;
        margin:0;
        }
        .headline{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0px 0px 0px 60%;
        /*padding:0px 0px 0px 25%;
        position: relative;
        left:25%;
        top:0px;*/
        float: right;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:black;
        border-width:0px 0px 10px 0px;
        }
```

Comment: In notepad++ <!-- --> works and /* */ wont i tried changing it

Comment: @plook it only appears not to work because you have css in a `.html` file, however if you take my word for it and try it anyways you will see that it in fact works. To prove my point, create a `.css` file and then try using `/**/` to comment out your css, you will see it then change line colors.

Comment: @plook see this fiddle for an example https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/52/